# Is this a valid query that could allow to detect whether compression is supported or not?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I am developing against a demo Oracle instance and have no access to compression. My code has to detect whether compression is available or not. My thought was to run this statement in a try/catch block and set the flag accordingly:

```
CREATE TABLE D COMPRESS FOR ARCHIVE AS SELECT * FROM dual;
```

Can anyone with access to an Enterprise instance tell me if this is the correct query? For me, it always throws:

```
Error: ORA-64307:  Exadata Hybrid Columnar Compression is not supported for tablespaces on this storage type
```

I am not sure if it correctly tells me that my instance is not Enterprise, or there is a problem with the query itself.

Answer (score 2):

That syntax is for Hybrid Columnar Compression. HCC is a feature that requires special hardware, like Exadata, Pillar Axiom storage, or Oracle ZFS Storage Appliance.

You can not do this on any database and certainly not in most of them. Instead of the above you can use  this for basic or advanced compression:

```
CREATE TABLE D ROW STORE COMPRESS BASIC AS SELECT * FROM dual;
CREATE TABLE D ROW STORE COMPRESS ADVANCED AS SELECT * FROM dual;
```

If you want to check the availability of compression options, use this:

```
SQL> select parameter, value from v$option
     where parameter in ('Advanced Compression', 'Basic Compression');

PARAMETER            VALUE
-------------------- -----
Basic Compression    TRUE
Advanced Compression TRUE
```

The values will be `FALSE` in Standard Edition.

Keep in mind, Advanced Compression is an extra cost option and despite this, it still can not be properly disabled, so the above does not mean you are licensed to use it, it just means th option is available.